# Custom useMutation hook with Apollo Client and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

When using Apollo client, I find it quite tedious to manually update the cache for every mutation that requires an immediate UI update. I therefore decided to try to make a custom hook which updates the cache automatically.

The hook works but it seems a little "hacky" and I'm worried it might mess with the normal functioning of the cache. So I just wanted to ask if this hook seems like it should work ok?

Here's the code (where `mutationName` is the actual graphql mutation name and `fieldName` is the original graphql query name corresponding to the mutation):

```
export const useMutationWithCacheUpdate = (
  mutation,
  mutationName,
  fieldName
) => {
  const [createMutation, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(mutation, {
    update(cache, { data }) {
      data = data[mutationName];
      cache.modify({
        fields: {
          [fieldName]: (existingItems = []) => {
            const newItemRef = cache.writeFragment({
              data: data,
              fragment: gql`
                  fragment newItem on ${fieldName} {
                    id
                    type
                  }
                `,
            });
            return [...existingItems, newItemRef];
          },
        },
      });
    },
  });
  return [createMutation, { data, loading, error }];
};
```